# Setting default value after initialization in SelectField flask-WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I would like to pre-select the value for `SelectField` when displaying it to user. `default` argument works when it is passed at the time of instantiation but does not work once the field is initialized.

```
class AddressForm(Form):
    country = SelectField('Country',choices=[('GB', 'Great Britan'), ('US', 'United States')], default='GB')    # works
```

When I try to use `default` value to preselect option before presenting the form to user for editing, it doesn't work.

```
address_form = AddressForm()
address_form.country.default='US'    # doesnot work
```

Need a solution to set default value to pre-set values before presenting to the user.

Scenario 2: Also does not work

```
class AddressForm(Form):
        country = SelectField('Country')    # works

address_form = AddressForm()
address_form.country.choices=[('GB', 'Great Britan'), ('US', 'United States')]
address_form.country.default='US'    # doesnot work
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once an instance of the form is created, the data is bound. Changing the default after that doesn't do anything. The reason changing `choices` works is because it affects validation, which doesn't run until `validate` is called.

Pass default data to the [form constructor](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#the-form-class), and it will be used [if no form data was passed](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-blank-input-not-go-back-to-the-default-value). The default will be rendered the first time, then posted the second time if the user doesn't change the value.

```
form = AddressForm(request.form, country='US')
```

(If you're using Flask-WTF's `Form` you can leave out the `request.form` part.)

Answer (score 9):

I know that you probably fixed the problem. But I think it doesn't work anymore. And because this is the first thing that shows up when googleing the problem, I want to give people with this problem a working solution(at least for me).

To confirm the change of the default choice, we have to add `address_form.process()`
.
Thats it!

The full solution would be:

```py
class AddressForm(Form):
        country = SelectField('Country')    # works

address_form = AddressForm()
address_form.country.choices=[('GB', 'Great Britan'), ('US', 'United States')]
address_form.country.default='US'
address_form.process()    # works
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for sharing!  One thing to note is that if you are pre-populating the form when rendering by manually setting address_form.state.data = 'CA' for example, the process() method will wipe your manual settings out.  You have to update your dropdown default and call process before setting any other input values manually.

Comment: This works for me but removes the CSRF protection as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64155651/4204032. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```py
class AddressForm(Form):
    country = SelectField('Country')    # works

address_form = AddressForm()
address_form.country.choices=[('GB', 'Great Britan'), ('US', 'United States')]
address_form.country.default='US'
address_form.process()
```

this method show the default as well but when i submit the form doesn't submitted , the validated method works correctly

Comment: For some reason when I try this i get an error saying "process() missing 1 required positional argument: 'formdata'". Is this because my form is a FlaskForm instead of just a Form?